# Modify Graylog URL

Tags: graylog3

I need to change the URL currently working from [https://10.1.1.1:9000](https://10.1.1.1:9000/) to https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog. This change works parcially, I am able to access

- Search: https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/search
- Streams: https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/streams
- Alerts: https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/alerts
- Dashboards: https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/dashboards
- Sources: https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/sources#3600

But System is replacing wrongly the URL: 
https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/graylog/system/overview

The change in the config file to modify the URL is as follows:

```
# Default: http://$http_bind_address/
http_publish_uri = https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog

# Default: $http_publish_uri
http_external_uri = https://10.1.1.1:9000/graylog/
```

Do you know if other configuration needs to be modified?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graylog 3.0.1 released on April 1st, 2019 fixes this issue:

```
Fix running Graylog web interface under a path prefix. Graylog2/graylog2-server#5702 Graylog2/graylog2-server#5703
```

In addition, new version fixes these other [issues](http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/changelog.html).